# SSIS Flat File error "Text was truncated or one or more characters had no match in the target code page."

Tags: sql-server, ssis, etl, bids

I am working on a SSIS project. I have a Flat File Source (csv) and OLE DB as destination. I have a column named `WrapUpName` with a data type `Unicode string [DT_WSTR]` with a `Outputcolumnwidth - 50` that only contains either of these data `Successfull,Unsuccessfull,ACPS FC: Always Busy or Ringing or Unattended` and my destination column is `nvarchar(50)`

I had these error message

> Data conversion failed. The data conversion for column "WrapUpName" returned status value 4 and status text "Text was truncated or one or more characters had no match in the target code page."

It's really weird because upon checking of the error row the data in column `WrapUpName` is `Successfull` which is handled by my IS with no problem. Upon researching I know that the fix is setting `code page` to `UTF-8` which I did from the first time or adjusting the length of data type which is correct but I want to know what triggered the error.

Comment: A mismatch between the code pages, perhaps UTF-8 and UTF-16 could be the source of the issue. You could also change the properties to "ignore" on truncation or error. Did you try that as well?

Comment: @TheEsisia not yet. I dont even know that its existed. I'll take a look. Please post your answer so I can upvote and accept it if your answer solved it.

Comment: @TheEsisia also is there is a downside when I did this? will my data will still be inserted?

Comment: If you have validated your data, then there shouldn't an issue. As I see you say that the length of the data is no more than 50 chars, so there is no truncation. But its always better to test first.

Comment: I ran into the case of having emoji () in a text column, resulting in the same error as you. Since I removed the emoji from the text, my CSV export hasn't had any problems.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Check out this link:

https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/32129879-90e1-491e-8c80-f3c3cf6eb0e0/how-to-avoid-truncation-error-in-ssis-for-flat-file?forum=sqlintegrationservices

Two ways for addressing the problem are described.

Comment: Yeah, I think this is the best answer for me in my case among the three that I found. Thanks, very much appreciated.

Comment: I had the exact same issue as above. Finally found the above link to work.  It puzzles me why SSIS would "truncate" a column when I validated each one with a max length of 123, going into a varchar(250)?  This should not happen, but at least this is a fix.  TY.

Answer (score 0):

Ok in my case I forgot to click a 'Unicode' check box in the SQL Server 'Select Source' page in the Export wizard.